# How can I manage this conversion from string to int?

Tags: c#, .net, string, int, type-conversion

Code :

```
int TopAttuale = Int32.Parse("1579.998779296875");
```

it says

> *System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.*

But that's what I have. How can I convert that string into INT (so 1579, I don't care about the comma)?

Comment: You don't have a comma but a dot/decimal `.` If you don't care about it, remove it from the string. If you do care about what is after the decimal, than convert it to a float or double and round it off with Math.Ciel and convert it then to an int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you should parse it as a `decimal` first, then just cast to `int`. (I'd use `decimal` rather than `double` as you've really *got* decimal input; `decimal` will represent your source data more accurately. It shouldn't make any difference though, by the time you cast it.)

```
// Parse using the invariant culture so that it always uses "." as the
// decimal separator
decimal parsed = decimal.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int value = (int) parsed;
```

Alternatively, see if there's a decimal point, and if so trim everything after it, then parse the result.

Comment: With `decimal` I get `Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.`. With double I get `-2147483648` as result :S

Comment: In fact double() returns `1,57999877929688E+15` :O

Comment: @markzzz: You shouldn't have done for the value you've given in the question. Perhaps you didn't give real sample data? Note the use of the invariant culture in my sample code.

Answer (score 9):

Do:

```
(int) double.Parse(inputstring)
```

Comment: `int TopAttuale = (int)double.Parse("1579.998779296875");` the result on `Response.Write(TopAttuale);` is -2147483648?

Comment: @markzzz What are you talking about? `TopAttuale` will hold the value `1579`. If you don't want to use parse methods from another reason, you can check out my answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
decimal.ToInt32(decimal.Parse("1579.998779296875"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to convert a floating point value in integer, which is directly not possible.
but if u have to do it than first convert string in double then convert double in integer.

```
       string str = "1579.998779296875";
        double val = Convert.ToDouble(str);
        int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Decimal.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse.aspx) method and [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) it to `int`:

```
int TopAttuale = (int) Decimal.Parse(inputString)
```

or use [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557) method:

```
string value;
decimal number;

value = "1579.998779296875";
if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
   int result = (int) number;
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}'.", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply ignores everything that would come after the decimal point.
Be warned, that this doesn't let you know if the string wasn't a number at all.

```
public int IntFromString(string str)
{
    int result = 0;

    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if (!char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            break;
        }

        result = result * 10 + c - '0';
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
decimal a= decimal.Parse("1579.998779296875");
a=Math.Floor(a);
int b=(int)a;
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

It displays 1579. As you need.